# LibGDX on Android TV

Tags: android, libgdx

Anybody wrote games for Android TV using LibGDX?

What is the mapping of the remote control?

Can we use the game controller with LibGDX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Android TV remotes use the Dpad controls:

```
android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP

android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER
```

You can find the full list here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER

Comment: Please extend your answer a little so people can get an idea without clicking the link you gave.